# How to disable folder view?

Tags: google-drive

I'm used to opening links in new tabs by clicking them with **middle mouse button**, but Google Drive decided to override that to also open them in some useless "Folder View" mode that doesn't allow for much readability of the contents and displays a lot less contents of the folder than a normal view mode (list of document names with details).

Is there a way to permanently disable this behavior? Or maybe override this behavior so it just opens links in new tabs, but without "Folder View" mode? Or maybe even redirect from "Folder View" to normal view automatically?